Powershell : Format output from database table to CSV File
When I try to run the powershell command below which is not giving the CSV table format instead its just a string (attached results Screenshot), I need help in table format with these results.
        $scriptCode = @'
        $query = "use test_MO; 
        SELECT Quantity, 'License Metric', 'Product Name', 'Manufacturer (Article)', 'Manufacturer article number (Article)','Article description (Article)','Purchase requisition number','Order number','License status','Maintenance end date'
        FROM licenses lic
        "

        $sql_job = Invoke-Sqlcmd  -ServerInstance $servername -Query "$Query"
        $sql_job
'@

        Remove-Item -Path "sqllicensereport.ps1" -Force
        New-Item -Path . -Name "sqllicensereport.ps1" -ItemType "file" -Value "$scriptCode"  | out-null
        $runquery = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ServerRGName  -VMName $ServerName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath                        "sqllicensereport.ps1" -Parameter @{servername = $servername}
        $temp = $runquery.Value[0].Message | Format-Table -Auto > $outputFile

Note: Export-CSV command but got the length (i put here in the comments, could anyone help here
Output now:

Results Expected from my end in below CSV sample:

Attaching the Output File and I would like to convert it to CSV (row and column format)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $run
Value[0]        :
Code          : ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded
Level         : Info
DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
Message       :               : Microsoft Windows Server Datacenter Core (Single Language)
Manufacturer (Article)                : Microsoft
Manufacturer article number (Article) : AAA-30385
Article description (Article)         : Microsoft Windows Server Datacenter 2 CORE Single Language Software Assurance
MPSA
Purchase requisition number           :
Order number                          :
License status                        : Active with Support
Maintenance end date                  : 2027-01-31
Quantity                              : 100
License Metric                        : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Suite Datacenter Core
Product Name                          : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Suite Datacenter Core
Manufacturer (Article)                : Microsoft
Manufacturer article number (Article) : AAA-30467
Article description (Article)         : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Datacenter 2 CORE mul License incl.
Software Assurance MPSA
Purchase requisition number           :
Order number                          :
License status                        : Active with Support
Maintenance end date                  : 2027-01-31
Quantity                              : 100
License Metric                        : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Suite Datacenter Core
Product Name                          : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Suite Datacenter Core
Manufacturer (Article)                : Microsoft
Manufacturer article number (Article) : AAA-30467
Article description (Article)         : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Datacenter 2 CORE mul License incl.
Software Assurance MPSA
Purchase requisition number           :
Order number                          :
License status                        : Active with Support
Maintenance end date                  : 2027-01-31
Quantity                              : 100
License Metric                        : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Suite Datacenter Core
Product Name                          : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Suite Datacenter Core
Manufacturer (Article)                : Microsoft
Manufacturer article number (Article) : AAA-90044
Article description (Article)         : Microsoft Core Infrastructure Server Suite Datacenter 16 Core mul Software
Assurance MPSA
Purchase requisition number           : RGBR0010499
Order number                          : PCSL0000467
License status                        : Active with Support
Maintenance end date                  : 2025-01-31
Quantity                              : 100
License Metric                        : Microsoft Windows Server Datacenter Core (SA)
Product Name                          : Microsoft Windows Server Datacenter Core
Manufacturer (Article)                : Microsoft
Manufacturer article number (Article) : AAA-90058
Article description (Article)         : Microsoft Windows Server Datacenter 16 Core incl. Azure Hybrid Benefit mul
Software Assurance MPSA
Purchase requisition number           :
Order number                          :
License status                        : Active with Support
Maintenance end date                  : 2025-01-31
Quantity                              : 100
License Metric                        : Microsoft Windows Server Standard Core (SA)
Product Name                          : Microsoft Windows Server Standard Core
Manufacturer (Article)                : Microsoft
Manufacturer article number (Article) : AAA-90065
Article description (Article)         : Microsoft Windows Server Standard 16 Core mul Software Assurance MPSA
Purchase requisition number           :
Order number                          :
License status                        : Active with Support
Maintenance end date                  : 2025-01-31
Value[1]        :
Code          : ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded
Level         : Info
DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
Message       :
Status          : Succeeded
Capacity        : 0
Count           : 0
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

To export the PowerShell output to excel, you can use Export-Csv
Here is the command to export the output to Excel
$runquery | Export-Csv -Path "C:\path\to\output\sqllicensereport.csv" -NoTypeInformation

You are using the wrong command.
The command to get a CSV is Export-Csv
$temp = $runquery.Value[0].Message |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $outputFile -NoTypeInformation

if you are using Powershell 7 you can remove -NoTypeInformation

Thanks for the quick update but its not working:
Result:  "Length" "4096"


Powershell : Format output from database table to CSV File

Here is a PowerShell script to convert the data stored in the parameter $outputMessage into an Excel format.
$outputMessage | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ":" -PropertyNames "Property", "Value" | Export-Csv -Path "vmdata1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv -Path "vmdata1.csv" | Export-Excel -Path "venkat.xlsx" -AutoSize -BoldTopRow

Output:

=
